# An $A_{\infty}$ space produces an $ A_{\infty}$ algebra

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I am looking for an elementary reference, other than the original paper of Stasheff, for a proof of the following fact:

if $Y$ is an $A_{\infty}$ space, the singular chain complex of $Y$ is an $ A_{\infty}$-algebra.

A proof is also welcome.

Comment: I don't know a good reference, but the idea is: the eilenberg-zilber map means that if $O$ is an operad in spaces then, $S_*(O)$ is an operad in chain complexes, and if $X$ is an $O$ algebra, then $S_*(X)$ is an $S_*(O)$ algebra. This is all fairly formal once you have the EZ-map. Now, the challenge is to show that $S_*(A_\infty)$ is equivalent to $A_\infty$ (chain version). This is easy if you have the somewhat fancy fact that $A_\infty$ is cofibrant in chains. In that case (depending on if you include the symmetric group action), it is easy to see that $S_*(A_\infty)\simeq S_*(Ass)= Ass$ .

Comment: From the last fact, you use the equivalence (in chains) $A_\infty \to Ass$ and  you get an equivalence $A_\infty \to S_*(A_\infty)$. This means that for an $A_\infty$ space $X$, $S_*(X)$ is an $A_\infty$ algebra. In practice, this means turning space homotopies into chain homotopies, and it is possible to do it by hand, but conceptually this is the idea.

Comment: Thanks! @Justin.  I didn't view it in the general setting before.

Comment: I should mention that there is a CW-structure on $A_\infty$ (space version) so that the cellular chains $C_*(A_\infty) = A_\infty$. This is another way to see the above. Hopefully all this makes clear why a direct proof is a bit messy.